# What is the function of `cite` below each question & answer?

Tags: support

I, today, saw one new thing below my question `cite` . I pressed it & this appeared:

> Example citation:
>
> user36790 (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/36790/user36790), Why does Hamiltonian follow the property $H^*_{ij} = H_{ji} $?, URL (version: 2015-07-31): [Why does Hamiltonian follow the property $H^*_{ij} = H_{ji} $?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197101)
>
> BibTeX  amsrefs
>
> @MISC {197101,
>       TITLE = {Why does Hamiltonian follow the property $H^*_{ij} = H_{ji} $?},
>       AUTHOR = {user36790 (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/36790/user36790)},
>       HOWPUBLISHED = {Physics Stack Exchange},
>       NOTE = {URL:[Why does Hamiltonian follow the property $H^*_{ij} = H_{ji} $?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197101) (version: 2015-07-31)},
>       EPRINT = {[Why does Hamiltonian follow the property $H^*_{ij} = H_{ji} $?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197101)},
>       URL = {[Why does Hamiltonian follow the property $H^*_{ij} = H_{ji} $?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197101)}
>
> }
>
> \bib{197101}{misc}{
>       title={Why does Hamiltonian follow the property $H^*_{ij} = H_{ji} $?},
>       author={user36790 (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/36790/user36790)},
>       note={URL: [Why does Hamiltonian follow the property $H^*_{ij} = H_{ji} $?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197101) (version: 2015-07-31)},
>       eprint={[Why does Hamiltonian follow the property $H^*_{ij} = H_{ji} $?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197101)},
>       organization={Physics Stack Exchange}
>   }

Even yesterday I didn't see it. I really don't know what these mean; I am really ignorant of these stuffs.

Can anyone explain what this `cite` is actually meant for? What is its function?

---

[image: image without "cite"]

[image: image with "cite"]

Comment: How do you get the image of the site from the past?

Comment: @Ooker: What do you want to know?

Comment: i mean, if you are not aware that tomorrow the site is changed, then why do you take the image of it today, so that you can use it to ask tomorrow?

Comment: @Ooker: I love conspiracy theories! No, actually, you know about India? At most of the places, the internet speed is less than that of snail's pace; sometimes it becomes dead!! So, I generally don't close most of the pages I couldn't complete reading at the night & let them stay for the next morning or so without shutting down my laptop but rather letting it hibernate. This is the case here. I had the previous page & so I took the shot; that's it:)

Answer (score 5):

The posts made on any StackExchange site are licensed by the [CC-SA-3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). This means if you use the content, or derive from the content, on the site you must provide a link to the original and to the original user (essentially -- I summarized, go read those links for more information).

If you did this on a website, that's pretty easy to manually include the `<a></a>` tags and do what you need to do. However, if you are writing lecture notes, or a journal article, or a thesis, or something like that, it isn't always as easy. The `cite` button that you refer to gives you a citation in [BibTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX) format as well as a LaTeX `bibitem` format. One can use these when typesetting a document using [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) and a citation will occur where desired and the bibliography will contain the full information required by the license.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised SE didn't post something about it themselves...

If you check [this answer to a post on meta.Mathoverflow,](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2436/35355) it looks like having a "cite" link originated on Mathoverflow, back in the SE 1.0 days.  SE recently changed the way the cite link is laid out (based on comments/complaints about it 2 years ago) and applied the change to MO, Phys.SE and a couple other SE sites.

Comment: Can you tell me, sir, what this is meant for?